# How can I change in db values of model object by celery worker with redis in Django?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I want to create an app with workers which in the background changes the value of Simulation model. Firstly user clicks to start simulation, wait some time, click to end simulation, and then on the page shows a value difference (from the start to the end of simulation) which was changed by the background worker. The main problem that I just can't reach the worker's task. I can reach @receiver after Simulation model saved and correctly check model`s values but I cant change model values in db by workers.

The project called app, application - myapp.

app/myapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Simulation(models.Model):
        # changed every simul day
        created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        today = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
        status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        daemon_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        info = models.TextField()

        def get_simulation_day(self):
            """days passed after simulation firstly start"""
            # sim = Simulation.objects.all().last()
            return (self.today - self.created_date).days
```

app/myapp/views.py

```
def simulate(request, action):
    sim = get_simulation()
    if action == "disable" and sim.status == True:
        sim.status = False
        sim.save()
    elif action == "enable" and sim.status == False:
        print('view simulate ok')
        sim.status = True
        sim.save()
        print('view simulate ok after save')
    context = {
            "simulations_exists": True,
            "days_passed": sim.get_simulation_day(),
            "simulation_today_str": (sim.today).strftime("%d %B, %Y"),
            "simulation_status": sim.status
    }
    return render(request, "simulation_page.html", context=context)
```

app/myapp/tasks.py

```
import logging

from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from app.celery import app

from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Simulation
# import myapp.models

@app.task
def simulate_days(sim_id):
    sim = Simulation.objects.get(id=sim_id)
    print('\n\nstart in simulate_days\n\n')
    it = 0
    while sim.status == True:
        it += 1
        print(f'\n\n {it} iter in simulate_days\n\n')
        sim.daemon_active = True
        sim.today = sim.today + timedelta(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        sim.refresh_from_db() 
        sim.save()
        sim.refresh_from_db() 
    print('\n\nend in simulate_days\n\n')
    sim.daemon_active = False
    sim.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Simulation)
def simulation_daemon(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.status == True and instance.daemon_active == False:
        print('start simulation_daemon')
        simulate_days.delay(instance.id)
        print('end simulation_daemon')
```

in app/settings.py I use postgres and add redis settings

```
# REDIS related settings 
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600} 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
```

in app/celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Before start server I firstly setup redis and then celery and it works as it expected. For redis I type in console:

```
redis-server
```

and i get:

```
[14604] 20 Nov 23:12:55 - DB 0: 4 keys (1 volatile) in 8 slots HT.
[14604] 20 Nov 23:12:55 - 11 clients connected (0 slaves), 1280840 bytes in use
```

for celery:

```
celery worker -A app --loglevel=debug --concurrency=4
```

in output i get

```
[2019-11-20 23:12:03,182: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
[2019-11-20 23:12:04,184: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by using `refresh_from_db` right after you changed to value of `today` in your task. This will cause any changed values to be overwritten with whatever is saved in the database. In this cause it would never allow the `today` value to be changed.

```
        sim.today = sim.today + timedelta(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        sim.refresh_from_db() # This will overwrite the `today` value you set in the line above
        sim.save() # This will just save the old value that was already in the DB
```

Comment: there is not a problem inside the task, I rewrite it many times with refresh, without. The main problem that I cant reach task from the receiver. BTW I already try apply_async instead of delay and it didn't help me.

Comment: ofc I can call this task just like a custom function but like background task I cant

Comment: @Max so your issue is that your Celery task is never run?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeees